# Can I make a semicircular collision in Godot?

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, game-engine, game-physics, godot

I made a semicircular 2D shape in Godot. Now I'm trying to give it proper collisions. So far, I've found no way to do this. The CollisionShape2D node only allows simple shapes like circles and rectangles, and the CollisionPolygon2D shape won't allow me to make the curved shape I require. Is there any way I can get the proper collisions?

Comment: Closest I can find is this - It seems someone has created a (supposedly) working GitHub repo that can convert sprites to collision shapes. The link to the repo is in the post - it says 3.0, but it is indeed for 3.1. Have a look and see if it's worth anything to you. -- https://www.reddit.com/r/godot/comments/9lbttx/how_to_draw_custom_collisionshape2d_godot_30/

Comment: EDIT - it seems that in the post I recommended, they discuss how CollisionPolygon can't do curves, and even how circular CollisionShapes are not true curves and are  simply drawn using a lot of verticies. Perhaps the best way is to just manually "approximate" the curves you need using the same method. If, however, you want to avoid drawing the shapes manually over and over, for that, the above recommendation may still be valid.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with a built-in function that does this.

However, you can do two things:

1. Approximate the circular shape with the CollisionPolygon2D. This is simple and will work. However, might not be very efficient.
2. You override the collision method for your object. It is also simple:

Say it is a semicircle in the direction head_dir. Simply:

```
dir := head_dir
position := this object position
circRadius := semi-circle radius
otherPos := other object position
inside = false
if(dotProduct(dir, otherPos) >= 0):
    inside = true
if(inside):
    if(norm(otherPos - position) > radius)
        inside = false
return inside
```

The second method will give you the exact collision you look for. All you need is update head_dir.

Comment: Hi what does norm(otherPos - position) mean?

Comment: I believe youve made some mistakes with this formula.  In the line; "if(norm(otherPos - position) > radius)" radius should be the combined radius length not just one of the circles radi.  Also i had to switch the sign of the x component of the otherPos depending on if the semi circle x pos was greater then the circles or less.

Comment: Same thing for the y component.

Comment: @dylan The formula merely says if a position (otherPos) is inside the semicircle. I believe the combined radius you mentioned would be used in collision detection with another semicircular shape, and yes, you are correct to use the combined radius.